# Application Insights response code 400 Bad request

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

when trying to call application insights api service with this url it gave me 400 Bad request

https://api.applicationinsights.io/beta/apps/appID/events/pageViews?timespan=P30D&$filter=contains(pageView/url,'valid-url')&$count=true

appID and valid-url is set correctly and i delete them in this question to make it more easy to read

Is there any issue in using $filter=contains ???

Comment: Looking at the documentation here: https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Events, I don't think `contains` method is supported.

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri i test it also with startswith which is supported and it gave me the same error

Comment: How are you calling the API? If you are doing it programmaticaly then in your code you could catch the web exception and read its response stream. Generally you should find more details about the error.

Comment: 'HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(req).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                return response.ReasonPhrase;
            }'

This is how i call the API using GetAsync() method
@GauravMantri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way to verify this stuff is to use the api explorer, and the demo app:

https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/events

this url shows that startswith works fine:

```
https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/events?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&eventType=pageViews&timespan=P30D&$filter=startswith(pageView%2Furl%2C'http%3A%2F%2Faiconnect')
```

if you "need" something like contains, you can use $search (which looks across most fields, though, and has its own AND/OR text search logic)

```
https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/events?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&eventType=pageViews&timespan=P30D&$search=%22Customers%2FCreate%22
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any workthrought that enable us to export application insights data to database as api call talkes too long time
@John Gardner

Comment: if you don't want to make queries for the service but want to directly export data, there's the Continuous Export feature, which is part of the enterprise (paid) features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-telemetry .  The REST service is intended for doing queries and has limits on the number of calls you can make within a period, etc.